# logit and probit models

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics, logistic-regression, standard-error

## Basic background

Hi, I'm relatively new to statistics and mathematics stack exchange so please bear with me.

I'm trying to learn about the probit and logit models where the observables $y$ can only take the binary values $y = 0$ (failure) or $y = 1$ (success) for a given dependent variable $x$. I'm primarily interested in features associated with fitting a logit and probit curve to a set of data of the form $\{x_i,y_i\}.$

The starting point seems relatively straightforward in that the probability of success given some particular value of $x$ can be expressed as
$$P(y=1|x) = F(\alpha + \beta x)$$
where $F$ is a linear transformation used to map $\alpha + \beta x$ to the probability interval $[0,1]$. For the logit and probit models we choose the functions
$$F(z)\equiv \Lambda(z) = \frac{e^z}{1+e^z} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$$
and
$$F(z)\equiv \Phi(z) = \int_{-\infty}^z \phi(u) du$$
respectively. Here $\phi$ is the normal pdf and $\phi$ the normal CDF. A plot reveals that the curves look very similar, so my guess is the choice of a probit and logit model is relatively unimportant for this one dimensional example. Yet, I have read and derived for myself that the probit model emerges naturally when considering latent variables with normally distributed error terms.

- My first question is whether or not the choice of logit vs probit is unimportant or are there good reasons to choose one over the other in modelling certain situations?

## Curve fitting

As far as I understand the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are usually derived by using maximum likelihood estimation (which I know very little about). Concretely the log--likelihood can be expressed as
$$l = \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \ln \left[F(\alpha + \beta x_i)\right] + (1-y_i) \ln\left[1-F(\alpha + \beta x_i)\right]$$
and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are estimated by solving the equations
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \alpha} = 0 \quad \frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta} = 0$$
simultaneously by some numerical method which is standardly implemented in programs such as R, mathematica, matlab, etc.

So now I imagine that I can use some data of the form $\{x_i,y_i\}$ to obtain some estimates for $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ in some numerical program. Some, I imagine, standard questions then pop to my mind:

- What is the standard error of $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ and how is it defined/calculated?
- What is the 95% confidence interval of $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ and how is it defined/calculated?
- I can use my fitted model $\hat{p}=\hat{F}(\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}x)$ to calculate probabilities of certain $x$ values not included in my dataset. I would then obtain a $(x,\hat{p})$ graph. But how do I calculate the 95% confidence interval of the predicted probabilities that my model outputs? [I imagine graphically it would look something like this, where the upper and lower curves are the confidence intervals. The middle curve is the predicted probabilities.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B61yt.png)

[The penultimate question seems to be handled to some extent in this link.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26616/how-can-i-compute-and-plot-the-95-confidence-bands-for-a-fitted-logistic-regres) However, I emphasize that the details are rather unclear to me. The lower (upper) confidence interval seems to be expressed on a form
$$\text{Lower (upper) confidence interval} = \text{estimated model}\,\hat{p} - (+) 1.96\sqrt{\chi^T C\chi}$$
similar to the standard expression for the 95% confidence interval of a normal distribution. Here $\chi$ is a vector presumably related to the datapoints and $C$ is some matrix called the covariance matrix.

Comment: For your first question, the practical difference is usually small, though the $\beta$ will mean different things in the two models and so have different values for the same input data.  A big advantage of the logit model is that the results can be translated into odds ratios and so may be easier to explain to an informed audience.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this answers the first question!